# Pip Install MySQLdb Failing in Virtualenv

Tags: virtualenv, mysql-python

I'm trying to install the MySQLdb module from a virtual environment (running python 2.7) on an EC2 instance:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09
```

with the command: `pip install MySQLdb`

It's failing with the line:

```
_mysql.c:29:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I assume it is because I am missing python-devel.  However when I try to install python-devel using `yum install python-devel` I am told I have to install it as the root user.  When I run `sudo yum install python-devel` as the root I get the message: `Package python26-devel-2.6.9-2.88.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version`.  Which looks to me like it's installing a version for python 2.6.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing below packages outside of venv, and then try to installing `MySQLdb`

```
sudo yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-common mysql-libs python-devel python-setuptools gcc
```

Comment: Still getting this error `_mysql.c:29:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`